# 'Go back' Button

Tags: xcode4.5

In Xcode, I've got one ViewController segued to a  second, and on the second I've got a 'go back' button:

The initial programming was:

```
- (IBAction)onBackButtonPressed:(id)sender {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

But as of iOS 6 the code has deprecated - what should I use then?

I'm a beginner, and basically want to programme a button which takes me back to the original ViewController from my second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new method you could use is:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: It simulated perfectly, but then when I clicked the 'go back' button, it crashed:

Came up with:
2012-12-17 00:09:20.549 Test1[4248:11303] Unknown class FamilyDetailerViewController in Interface Builder file.
2012-12-17 00:09:25.614 Test1[4248:11303] -[FamilyDetailViewController onBackButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75b51c0
2012-12-17 00:09:25.617 Test1[4248:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FamilyDetailViewController onBackButtonPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75b51c0'

Comment: Ok. Do you have a method called onBackButtonPressed in that view controller? Is it defined in the header?

Comment: I did, then decided to redo the connections from scratch for the button and it works!
Thank you so much - common sense beats me late at night...